# Android app no launch icon

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest

I have put together a simple application and when I am installing the app the icon displays but once it's installed there is no launch icon.
Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.SiteTools.convertme"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/launch_icon"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>

</manifest>
```

I have tried renaming the icons but it hasn't helped, I have tested on two devices and neither get the launch icon.
I use eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an Intent Filter, or else Android won't know what application to launch. Also, your application should include the name of the app. I've included a name below as `someActivity`, change it to your app as appropriate. This can be done by changing your application to the following:

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/launch_icon"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity 
        android:name="someActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Good point, guess I didn't go quite far enough... Fixed it to be inside the `activity` tag.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto : An `Activity` isn't an 'app' why name it `someApp`?

Comment: Thanks PearsonArtPhoto that has given me my launch icon, upon opening the application with icon I get the alert "The application ConvertMe (process come.SiteTools.convertme) has stopped unexpectedly."
I updated "someActivity" to ".MainActivity" and "ConvertMe" but still got the same error message.

Comment: What is the name of your main activity? That is the name you should use. You might need to use the full name (`com.SiteTools.convertme....`)

Comment: I have noticed that I don't have any files under /src so I don't have an activity file, I'll see if I can build one, other wise I guess I need to start a new project.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create icons for all resolutions ? . Under your res folder add the appropiate icon size for each folder.

drawable-hdpi
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-xhdpi

Your device should pick it up from there according to its resolution